# What criteria should I consider when choosing a domain register?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, server, blog, looking-for-hosting

I want to create a blog with my own domain and there are many companies which offer the same domain for different prices.  Do they offer different services at different price points or does their reputation does depend on other aspects (reliability, support, etc)?

Which criteria do I consider to choose among them?

Comment: This would be off-topic if it were asking for recommendations of domain registrars.   But asking for criteria for choosing should be just fine.